# Transfer proxmox raw disk to hyper-v

Tags: virtual-machine

I run several proxmox in my lab. Now I want to play with hyper-v and avoid creating virtual mashines from scratch.
Can you recommend any tools for raw to vhdx conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in *qemu-img convert* command, it supports **vhd**,
example:

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vpc vdisk.img hyper-v.vhd
```

Link: https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html

For **raw>vhdx** conversion try Starwind V2V convertor - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter